# Is there a maximum limit to the size of a variable that should be allocated on a stack?

Tags: c, struct, variables, stack

i declared a struct variable in C of size greater than 1024bytes. On running Coverity (a static code analyzer application) it reports that this stack variable is greater than 1024 bytes and therefore a cause of error.
I'd like to know if I need to worry about this warning? Is there really a maximum limit to the size of a single stack variable?

thanks,
che

Comment: Picking 1024 is completely arbitrary, a 512 byte variable can be a "cause of error" too.  And a 2048 byte variable doesn't make it twice as likely.  Take this advice with a pound of salt.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum size of a variable is the limited by the maximum size of the stack (specifically, how much of the stack is left over from any current use including variables and parameters from functions higher on the stack as well as process frame overhead).

On Windows, the stacksize of the first thread is a property of the executable [set during linking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8cxs58a6.aspx) while the stacksize of a thread can be specified during [thread creation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686774%28VS.85%29.aspx).

On Unix, the stacksize of the first thread is usually only limited only by how much room there is for it to grow.  Depending on how the particular Linux lays out memory and your use of shared objects, that can vary.  The stacksize of a thread can also be specified during [thread creation](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_attr_setstacksize.html).

Answer (score 3):

The problem it is trying to protect you from is stack overflow, because of different execution paths, it is very hard to find in testing. Mostly for this reason - it is considered bad form to allocate a large amount of data on the stack. You are only really likely to run into a real problem on an embedded system though.

In other words, it sets an arbitrary limit to what it considers too much data on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Of course it's limited by the address space of your system.  It's also limited by the amount of space allocated to the stack by your OS, which usually can't be changed after your program starts but can be changed beforehand (either by the launching process, or by the properties of the executable).  At a quick glance, the maximum stack size on my OS X system is 8 MiB and on Linux it's 10 MiB.  On some systems, you can even allocate a different amount of stack to each different thread you start, although this is of limited usefulness.  Most compilers also have another limit to how much they'll allow in a single stack frame.

On a modern desktop, I wouldn't worry about a 1k stack allocation unless the function were recursive.  If you're writing embedded code or code for use inside an OS kernel, it would be a problem.  Code in the Linux kernel is only permitted 64 KiB stacks or less, depending on configuration options.

Comment: "On some systems, you can even allocate a different amount of stack to each different thread you start, although this is of limited usefulness". It becomes useful on systems where the default is tiny - you don't see the need on desktop linux, but you would on some embedded system with pre-allocated stacks and no virtual memory.

Answer (score 1):

This article is pretty interesting regarding stack size http://www.embedded.com/columns/technicalinsights/47101892?_requestid=27362

Yes is it OS dependent and also other *things* dependent. Sorry to be so vague. You may also be able to dig up some code in the gcc collection for testing stack size.

Answer (score 0):

If your function was involved (directly or indirectly) in recursion, then allocating a large amount on the stack would limit the depth of recursion and might well blow the stack. Under Windows this stack reserve defaults to 1MB, though you can increase it statically with linker commands. The stack will grow as it is used, but the operating system sometimes **cannot** extend it. I discuss this in a little more detail on my website [here](http://bobmoore.mvps.org/Win32/w32tip55.htm).

Answer (score 0):

As I have seen, a C compiler(turbo) provides a maximum size of 64000k for a variable. If we need more size, then it is declared as "huge".

Comment: The same message I have seen when I declared a variable as int a[1000][1000]. The compiler displayed an error message that "array size too large". When I saw help, it has the given same message

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to try to use a massive amount of stack space.

Here is a link to the default gcc stack size: http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/doc/stackOverflow.txt

Also, you could specify `--stack,xxxxx` to customize the stack size, so it's best to assume `xxxxx` is a small number and stick with heap allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Stack, heap, low, high VM -- Nuts, for the first thread, the stack at the top pf 64 bit VM, there should be no limit, so it seems like a gcc/c compiler bug that for local automatic "int x[2621440];" I get SIGSEGV.   The compiler should be letting the first thread stack grow until it hits the heap, which in a 16 billion billion byte VM is pretty unlikely for now.  The kindest thing is to call it a compiler "limitation".  (In testing some while back, probably on a Solaris SPARC, it seemed that local variables processed faster than global ones.  Go figure!)