# ".exe has stopped working" I am unable to initialize two structures of the same defined type. I'm using Eclipse in C on windows 7

Tags: c, eclipse, windows-7

```
int main(void) {
```

My issue is here, when I attempt to initialize two structures of type 'PGMImage'.
My error reads "Main.exe has stopped working"

```
    PGMImage img, rotateimg;
    getPGMfile("mandrill.pgm", &img);
    printf("width: %d, height: %d", img.width, img.height);


    return 0;
}
```

This is PGMImage:

```
typedef struct {unsigned char red;
                  unsigned char green;
                  unsigned char blue;
                 }RGB_INT;

struct PGMstructure
  {
    int maxVal;
    int width;
    int height;
    RGB_INT data[MAX][MAX];
};

typedef struct PGMstructure PGMImage;
```

Comment: The error looks to be in ``getPGMfile``...

Comment: Can you show us the `getPGMfile` function ?

Comment: 'getPGMfile' runs just fine for me. I want to create a function to rotate the PGM image, so I am creating a second PGMImage to work with my rotated image. However, I got 'getPGMfile' here: http://sun.iwu.edu/~shelley/sie/zoo/journal/pgm.c.html

Comment: I should clarify: the program lets me manipulate 'img'. The only problem occurs when I try to initialize 'rotateimg'.

Comment: So if in the `main` you have only `PGMimage img;` it works ??

Comment: Weird it is not working with me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, on windows by default it seems that the default size of the stack allocated for a program is 1MB.

But, with your program, when you do `PGMImage img`, you are allocating a way too much.

Explanation :

```
#define MAX 800 // Find it in your link

typedef struct {unsigned char red;
                  unsigned char green;
                  unsigned char blue;
                 }RGB_INT;

struct PGMstructure
  {
    int maxVal;
    int width;
    int height;
    RGB_INT data[MAX][MAX];
};

typedef struct PGMstructure PGMImage;
```

So when you do `PGMImage img`, you are allocating *4 bytes* + *4 bytes* + *4 bytes* + *800 x 800 x 3* bytes. It gives **1 920 012** bytes, in other words, almost 2 MB.

In cpp :

```
std::cout << "Sizeof PGMImage : " << sizeof( PGMImage ) << std::endl;

// gives : "Sizeof PGMImage : 1920012
```

So it is normal that on windows you get this error.

If you want to solve this error :

```
PGMImage* img = (PGMImage*)malloc( sizeof(PGMImage) );
```

And that's it ! The allocation on the Heap solve this problem, but don't forget to `free` it at the end !

*A good explanation of the reason of the limit on the stack : [Is there a maximum limit to the size of a variable that should be allocated on a stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152601/is-there-a-maximum-limit-to-the-size-of-a-variable-that-should-be-allocated-on-a)*

Comment: I entered `PGMImage* rotateimage = (PGMImage*)malloc( sizeof(PGMImage) );` I want to enter the values in the img struct into the rotateimage struct. Like this: `rotateimage.height = img->height`. It does not recognize 'rotateimage' as a struct, giving me an error "request for member 'height' in something not a structure or union"

Comment: `rotateimage->height` :) Take a look at : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b930c881(v=vs.71).aspx